# How can i solve this code test by using PHP?

Tags: php

I took the code test for the first time and did not solve this in 30min.
Would you please give me one of the answers solve this code test?

> Write a function:
>
> `function solution($A);`
>
> that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive
> integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.
>
> For example
>
> - given `A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]`, the function should return `5`.
> - Given `A = [1, 2, 3]`, the function should return `4`.
> - Given `A = [−1, −3]`, the function should return `1`.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range `[1..100,000];` each element of array A
> is an integer within the range `[−1,000,000..1,000,000]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more efficient way of getting it done, but here's something to get you going. It'll still loop up to 100,000 times which is quite a lot.

```
function solution($array) {
    $i = 1;
    while (in_array($i, $array)) $i++;
    return $i;
}
```

EDIT: and here's a more optimised solution that doesn't use `in_array`:

```
function solution($array) {
    
    // sort from smallest to largest
    sort($array);
    
    // try to find a positive break in the sequence
    $last = 0;
    if (end($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $current) {
            if ($current == $last) continue; // duplicate
            if ($current != $last + 1 && $current > 0) break;
            $last = $current;
        }
    }
    
    return $last + 1;
}
```

Comment: No need to remove negative values. When searching for a break in the sequence, don't break if `$current < 0`, i.e. just change `if ($current != $last + 1) break;` to `if ($current != $last + 1 && $current > 0) break;`.

Comment: @kmoser if all the values in the array are negative, it'll no longer return 1

Comment: True, but it looks like you updated your code to reduce the number of passes anyway.